# How to make a script that prints the multiples of a number using a for loop and range() function in python

Tags: python, function, loops, numbers, range

The multiples of number is when you add that number to it self multiple times.
range() generates a sequence of integer numbers. It can take one, two, or three parameters:

range(n): 0, 1, 2, ... n-1
range(x,y): x, x+1, x+2, ... y-1
range(p,q,r): p, p+r, p+2r, p+3r, ... q-1 (if it's a valid increment).

Comment: Did you try something? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is already implemented by the `range` function in python.

You can read its documentation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp).

Comment: Why arange function rather than normal range function, especially for a beginner?

Comment: as far as I am aware, vanilla `range` does not support custom increment values, and `np.arange` does. He is asking for that specifically.

Comment: [Range function signature](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) is  range(start, stop, step).  Step should be an integer which is sufficient for a multiplication table.  My concern is a beginner who is not quite sure on how to do a for loop and print to the screen should be focused on the core Python functions rather than  more advanced topics such as Numpy.

Comment: @DarrylG you are right. From memory I thought that the signature for range was just `range(start,stop)`, but it actually supports `step`. I guess I was fixated on not having fractional increments. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: No problem.  My concern is that beginners often start using libraries such as Numpy without a proper understanding of when it should be used.  Numpy is an optimized library for computations that can greatly speed up computations.  But, for small tasks or when used improperly can actually make the code slower.   That's why I was making this alert.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Also, there is no point in adding this dependency to whatever they are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This code with print all the multiples a given number `x`, `n` times

```
x = 2
n = 5
multiples = [x * i for i in range(1, n+1)]
print(multiples)
```

output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) itself - by setting third argument same as first, assuming that you want to get `10` multiplies of `3` you can do:

```
n = 3
k = 10
mult = list(range(n, (n*k)+1, n))
print(mult)  # [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30]
```

Note that due to first argument being inclusive and second being exclusive I need to add `1` to `n*k`, otherwise I would get 9 instead of 10 numbers. Keep in mind that range is designed for integer numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
def the_multiples_of_number(start_number,end_number,the_number_you_want_to_the_multiples):
    for x in range(start_number,end_number,the_number_you_want_to_the_multiples):
        print(x)
```

the_multiples_of_number(0,100,7) #it should prints out the multiples of 7 between 0 & 100

Comment: Please format your answer in a readable way. Also, don't just provide a code, include some explanation as to why that works and answers the question.

Comment: Code looks essentially correct, but may I suggest shorter variable names. 
Variable names such as `the_number_you_want_to_the_multiples` makes the code harder to follow.